# Missing variable in Laravel Mailable markdown view

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have created some mailables that require a course variable to populate some data in the markdown templates:

```
class CourseVisible extends Mailable implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * The course instance.
     *
     * @var Course
     */
    public $course;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Course $course)
    {
        $course->load(['award:id,name']);
        $this->course = $course;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->markdown('emails.course.visible');
    }
}
```

And I have tested this with the following route:

```
$course = Prospectus\Models\Course::find(13889);
Route::get('/course-visible', function () use ($course) {
    return new Prospectus\Mail\CourseVisible($course);
});
```

And everything works like a charm BUT!

When I call it in my actual code like this:

```
    $course->visible = ($course->visible == true ? false : true);
    $course->save();
    Mail::to($course->notifiableUsers())->send(new CourseVisible($course));
```

And the view:

```
# The {{ $course->award->name }} {{ $course->title }} ({{ $course->year }}) course has been published to the website.
```

I get a failed job and  the dreaded "ErrorException: Undefined variable: course" message...

If this helps, this is the data from Horizon:

```
{
  "mailable": {
    "course": {
      "class": "Prospectus\\Models\\Course",
      "id": 13889,
      "connection": "mysql"
    },
    "from": [],
    "to": [
      {
        "name": "XXXXXXXX",
        "address": "XXXXXXXXX"
      }
    ],
    "cc": [],
    "bcc": [],
    "replyTo": [],
    "subject": null,
    "markdown": null,
    "view": null,
    "textView": null,
    "viewData": [],
    "attachments": [],
    "rawAttachments": [],
    "callbacks": [],
    "connection": null,
    "queue": null,
    "chainConnection": null,
    "chainQueue": null,
    "delay": null,
    "chained": []
  },
  "tries": null,
  "timeout": null
}
```

If it is relevant, the application, horizon and the supervisor script are on separate server to the redis server and the MySQL server.

Can anyone shed any light on this? Thanks!

Comment: I'm guessing you're using `$course` in your view ? `return $this->markdown('emails.course.visible')`->with('course', $this->course);`

Comment: I have updated with a snippet from the view and I am not using the 'with' method as I believe according to the docs: " any public property defined on your mailable class will automatically be made available to the view"

Comment: $course->visible = ($course->visible == true ? false : true); is this line working??Have you tried delating this line

Comment: The missing $course variable is causing the issue so it’s not the visible property.